# Counting total number of paper pieces

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, adhoc, number-theory

The below is an interview question which I was unable to solve and needs some help.

Question:

A Person is playing with paper and during his game he folds the paper vertically in one turn and then horizontally in another turn and repeats the process n number of times. After he's done he cuts the paper vertically and horizontally. The task at hand is to take a number "N" as input and find the count of paper pieces that will be there after cutting the paper vertically and horizontally after folding it n times following the pattern as mentioned above.

```
Constraints:

1< N <10^5

N : Total number of turns
As the answer can be very large output the result mod 10^9+7
```

Test Cases

```
Input: 0
Output: 4

Input: 1
Output: 6

Input: 2
Output: 9

Input: 3
Output: 15
```

I tried to find some number pattern but couldn't find any also this question doesn't seem related to any algorithm and thus I was unable to find any proper approach. Please help suggesting some approach.

Comment: I would not try to find a pattern in the total numbers (the sequence 4, 6, 9, 15, ... doesn't ring a bell) but rather in the 4 subtotals you get at each iteration. At iteration n, the piece of paper is folded into 2^n layers. You cut it in four stacks. How many pieces per stacks? Write these four numbers and try to find a pattern for that. For instance, at iteration 2, the four stacks have: 1, 2, 2, 4 pieces, respectively.

Comment: I tried that too... but couldn't come up with any pattern... for example n=0, (1+1+1+1); n=1, (1+2+2+1); n=2, (1+2+4+2); n=3, (2+3+6+4); n=4, (4+6+9+6);  Here, the first number corresponds to paper pieces in top left, second is top right, third is bottom right and fourth is bottom left

Comment: Okay, maybe we can't come up with patterns by looking at the sequences, but we can still write a recurrence relation by thinking about the folding and cutting process. Can you write four formula to calculate the four numbers at iteration n+1, as functions of the four numbers at iteration n?

Comment: Let `f(x) = (2^x + 1)`. If N is even: the solution is `f(N/2) * f(N/2)`. If N is odd: the solution is `f((N-1)/2) * f((N+1)/2)`.

Comment: Thanks @Olivier, this was awesome and it is giving exact answer. I wonder how you reached to this formulae. Can you suggest some approach how you derived this.

Comment: Basically: with k cuts (in the same direction), you have k+1 pieces. So, with kv vertical cuts and kh horizontal cuts, you have (kv+1)*(kh+1) pieces. Everytime you fold vertically, kv is multiplied by 2, and the first value is 1, so kv is a power of 2. The same is true for kh. So the answer is in the form (2^x+1)*(2^y+1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments mentions, you should look for a pattern in the sections (4 corners) and not in the total parts.
We will enumerate the corners as a vector like this:

> (a (top left),b (top Right) ,c (bottom left) ,d (bottom Right))

Also for sake of consistency and understanding we always fold from right to left in the vertical fold (right half on top of the left half) and from bottom to top in the horizontal fold (bottom half on top of the top half) and we start with horizontal as the first fold we will preform.

first we start with 1 in each corner so when we divide we get the sum of all corners like this:

(1,1,1,1)  = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 4 (n = 0)

lets see what will happen in each corner after few runs:

(2,1,2,1) = 2 + 1 + 2 + 1 = 6 (n = 1)

(4,2,2,1) = 4 + 2 + 2 + 1 = 9 (n = 2)

(6,3,4,2) = 6 + 3 + 4 + 2 = 15 (n = 3)

(9,6,6,4) = 9 + 6 + 6 + 4 = 25 (n = 4)

maybe at first its hard to see the relation between but actually the pattern is pretty simple:

> (a,b,c,d) -> (a+b,a,c+d,c) when you fold vertically (from right to left)

and

> (a,b,c,d) -> (a+c,b+d,a,b) when you fold horizontally (from bottom to top)

so you can get the recursive relationship and here some simple code in C for this:

```
int func(int a, int b, int c, int d, int n) {
 if (n == 0) return (a + b + c + d);
 if (n % 2 == 0) return func(a + b, a, c + d, c, n - 1);
 else return func(a + c, b + d, a, b, n - 1);
}
```

from here you can get a better computational results but this is a start

Comment: If the four corners are referred to by position ("top left", etc) then please specify explicitly how the folds are performed. For instance, for a vertical fold, do you fold the left half onto the right half, or the right half onto the left half? The choice of course doesn't affect the total, but does permute the corner values.

Comment: Thanks @JackRaBeat, I think this is correct way to build base solution but maybe it'll give TLE. I think we can optimize this by some kind of tabular memorization i.e., dynamic programming. Actually I couldn't see the relation at first but this seems to be achievable now. Thanks for help !!!

Comment: How did you arrive at these recurrence relation and do you have a proof or other argument to support them?